# What is the reputation awarded for an accepted answer to a closed question?

Tags: support, reputation

What is the reputation awarded to an accepted answer for the question which are marked as duplicate, on hold etc., I know that it is +15 for an accepted answer for opened questions. Does it change for a duplicate question?

Recently, For [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/ramayana-ravana-and-lakshman/16195#16195) duplicate question I gained only 13 reputation even though it showed +15 in the reputation change and there was no down vote. Can any one explain the reason for this?

Comment: Because one of the post you edited got deleted, that gave you (-2). On dec 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. there is **always** 15 reputation is awarded for acceptance of one of your answer **regardless** the question is open or closed.

-2 should be for a downvote on one of your post or -1×2 for your downvoting to couple of post etc, though there are also other possibilities of voting on your posts that may result in +13.

Just click on achievement button to recheck it. More precisely check [Reputation tab from your profile activity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/5212/sree-charan?tab=reputation) page to understand any chances in reputation.

Anyway, the current page of your reputation history doesn't show any downvote or +13 recently. So, it may be undo of any voting operation by a user.

In addition to this, you may also supposed to check the  reputation history on your other SE communities/sites as the achievement popup may have combination of your reputation changes for multiple communities.

Tip: You can [audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/260388) your reputation by clicking [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/reputation)!

<s>[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20285/260388) MSE post may help for users who had 1 reputation.</s>

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: Can one answer even closed questions?I thought it was not possible.

Comment: @Rickross What? clarify/discuss at [chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)